# Time and date filter in SSRS 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am looking for an expression that can filter a time and date column to 4 hrs prior from what the actual value is.

Example: 5/27/2015
         5:00:30 pm

So I am looking how to get: 5/27/2015
                            1:00:30 pm

Answer (score 0):

To get the time 4 hours previous to the time given by the field 'Time':

```
=DateAdd(dateinterval.Hour,"-4",Fields!Time.Value)
```